# Deserializing an array using SOAP

Tags: c#, serialization, soap

I'm having a problem getting a SOAP service to deserialize an array of objects; its only reading in the first member of the array and nothing else. Here is my code:

```
public void StoreCredentials(Credentials credentials)
    {
        Credentials[] credsArray;
        var soap = new SoapFormatter();

        var stream = new FileStream(_path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        try
        {
            credsArray = (Credentials[])soap.Deserialize(stream);
            var credsList = credsArray.ToList();
            credsList.Add(credentials);
            credsArray = credsList.ToArray();
        }
        catch (SerializationException)
        {
            credsArray = new[] {credentials};
        }
        soap.Serialize(stream, credsArray);
        stream.Close();
    }
```

I wrote a simple unit test which adds two Credentials objects to the file, the output looks correct, both sets of credentials are present, but when I run the test to add a third set to the file, the soap.Deserialize(stream) line returns an array with only one entry, even though the file its reading from contains two entries. Am I doing something wrong here? Is there a better / easier way to do this? Please help!

Comment: Why are you playing with SOAPformatter? Why not just use WCF, which will do the serialization for you?

Comment: Why does your school make you do stupid things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem is with the FileMode.OpenOrCreate attribute of the FileStream. This will open the file but append it with a new collection instead of altering the original collection. I needed to overwrite the file by using FileMode.Create instead, so here is the working code (I also changed the collection to a Hashtable, which works better):

```
public void StoreCredentials(Credentials credentials)
    {
        credentials.Encrypt(_myUser.Encryption);
        Hashtable credsTable;
        var soap = new SoapFormatter();

        FileStream stream;
        try
        {
            stream = new FileStream(_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            credsTable = (Hashtable) soap.Deserialize(stream);
            stream.Close();
            stream = new FileStream(_path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            if (credsTable.ContainsKey(credentials.Id))
                credsTable[credentials.Id] = credentials;
            else
                credsTable.Add(credentials.Id, credentials);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            stream = new FileStream(_path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            credsTable = new Hashtable {{credentials.Id, credentials}};
        }
        soap.Serialize(stream, credsTable);
        stream.Close();
    }
```